# Add column to dataframe that sums values in another column based on list of characters in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Using this example data, I am trying to use the list of characters in the initial_seed and seed column to calculate the comb_score column in the intended result dataframe.

[image]

```
# For reproducing the data above:
initial_seeds <- as.character(list("1,2", "2,3", "3,4"))
mean <- c(5.6, 2.4, 6.5)

mean_data <- data.frame(cbind(initial_seeds,mean))

seed <- c(1,2,3,4)
score <- c(100,65,45,30)

score_data <- data.frame(cbind(seed,score))
```

I'm sure there's a way to do this by splitting the initial_seed column and removing the comma, but im wondering if there is a way to do this keeping
the initial_seed column a list of characters and the seed column as numeric? Is there a simple dplyr solution that I am overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible way to solve your problem:

```
library(dplyr)

mean_data %>% 
  group_by(initial_seeds) %>% 
  mutate(comb_score = sum(score_data$score[score_data$seed %in% strsplit(initial_seeds, ",")[[1]]])) %>% 
  ungroup()

#  # A tibble: 3 x 3
#    initial_seeds mean  comb_score
#    <chr>         <chr>      <dbl>
#  1 1,2           5.6          165
#  2 2,3           2.4          110
#  3 3,4           6.5           75
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mean_data %>% 
  #Create auxiliary variable 
  mutate(seed = initial_seeds) %>% 
  #Separate rows for each seed, using comma as separator
  separate_rows(seed,sep = ",") %>% 
  #Transform seed and mean variables to numeric
  mutate(across(.cols = -initial_seeds,.fns = as.numeric)) %>% 
  #Join with score_data
  left_join(score_data) %>%
  #Group by initial_seeds
  group_by(initial_seeds) %>% 
  #Summarise with mean and comb_score
  summarise(
    mean = unique(mean),
    comb_score = sum(score),
  )
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work.... you're trying to join the two dataframes by a column that doesn't exist in both df's (mean_data and score_data) and that you also dropped in your mutate call (initial_seeds).

Comment: Sorry, maybe I did not understand the problem, but when I used separate_rows I create the variable seed that I can use to join with score_data and after use to summarise and create comb_score